# oracle EM no display

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am trying to load oracle 12c EM in chrome and IE but I get:

"This webpage is not available" or "This page can't be displayed"

I can not browse it even from the server machine.

I have tested connection through SQL developer and it works.

I can ping the server and the database and listener are already started.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: What URL did you use to attempt to connect to EM?

Comment: https :// hostname : 5500 / em

Comment: Also I can not find emctl either. can not run "emctl start dbconsole" or "emctl status"

Comment: It seems that emctl is not available in 12c. Check this out - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2557217 I myself have not worked with 12c yet.

Comment: You can check the URL to use in this file as well: $ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini

Comment: portlist.ini is empty.

Comment: re-installed it. it worked.